# Difference between Linux Bridge and Open vSwitch

Tags: switch, linux, bridge, sdn, virtual

What are the most significant differences between how a Linux bridge and an Open vSwitch work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open vSwitch has a section on that in their [FAQ](http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/faq/general/):

> Q: Why would I use Open vSwitch instead of the Linux bridge?
>
> A: Open vSwitch is specially designed to make it easier to manage VM network configuration and monitor state spread across many physical hosts in dynamic virtualized environments. Refer to [Why Open vSwitch?](http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/intro/why-ovs/) for a more detailed description of how Open vSwitch relates to the Linux Bridge.

The entire list of features/differences ([Why Open vSwitch?](http://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/intro/why-ovs/)) is quite long, you should check it out if you want to know all the details. The short version is that Open vSwitch is targeted at large multi-server virtualisation environments, so it is focused on logical abstraction and management; the Linux bridge is fast and reliable, but lacks all fancy control features.